# cannot install postgresql-server-dev-all

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies, postgresql

i'm trying to install the package postgresql-server-dev-all but i'm getting this output from apt install:

> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or
>   been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to
>   resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
>   postgresql-server-dev-all : Depends: postgresql-server-dev-11 but it
>   is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have
>   held broken packages.

by apt install postgresql-server-dev-11 I get the following:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
>   postgresql-server-dev-11 : Depends: clang-7 but it is not going to be
>   installed
>                               Depends: libpq-dev (>= 11~~) but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held
>   broken packages.

And by apt install libpq-dev the following:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  libpq-dev : Depends:
>   libpq5 (= 11.2-1) but 11.5-0ubuntu0.19.04.1 is to be installed E:
>   Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Of course I did already apt update and apt upgrade before that, and my Ubuntu version is the latest 19.04.

Are there inconsistencies in the repository that are responsibility of the Ubuntu team or can I still fix this manually?

Comment: @N0rbert why would I need the Universe repository?

Comment: @fstab because of dependencies, at least of [`clang-7`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=clang-7&searchon=names&suite=disco&section=all)...